# Backup Script throwing errors

Tags: scripting, backup

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Finds all folders and subsequent files that were modified yesterday and dumps them out to a text

updatedb && rm /tmp/*

echo $(locate -b `date --date='yesterday' '+%Y.%m.%d'`) > /tmp/files.txt

#creates variable out of the file. 

input="/tmp/files.txt"

yest=$(date --date='yesterday' '+%Y.%m.%d')

#loops through each entry of folders

while IFS= read -r folders

do

echo $folders

tar -cvf $folders\.tar $folders --remove-files

done < "$input"
```

and it gives me the error:

```
tar: /backup/DNS/intns1/2016.07.19: Cannot open: Is a directory

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong...

Comment: There is a space in your filename, quote your vars.

Comment: There is so much that's wrong with that script it makes my eyes hurt to look at it.  Starting with: 1. there's no benefit to using `locate` instead of `find` if you're running `updatedb` immediately before it. 2. you're defining `$input` AFTER the first use of it as an output file. 3. you're defining `$yest` AFTER using the exact same date format in the `locate` command. 4. you're using a variable called `$folders` but you're feeding it a list of files, not directories. 5. you have no indentation in your code to make it more readable.  6. as @123 said, you're not quoting your variables.

Comment: Pretty much any time you do `echo $(some command)` you should ask yourself why not just `some command`. Don't mix and match `$(...)` with backticks; better still, just use the `$( ... )` style as it nests cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Using fairly recent GNU versions of `date`, `find`, `tar`, and `xargs`:

**This script needs bash or ksh or zsh or some other reasonably modern shell that understands [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) (`<(...)`)**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

    today='12am today'
yesterday='12am yesterday'

# function to create a tar file for a directory but only include
# files older than "$2" but newer than "$3".  Delete any files
# added to the tar archive.
#
# the tar file will be created uncompressed in the same directory
# as the directory itself.  e.g. ./dir --> ./dir.tar
function tarit() {
  dir="$1"
  older="$2"
  newer="$3"

  tar cvf "$dir.tar" -C "$dir/.." --null --remove-files \
    -T <(find "$dir" ! -newermt "$older" -newermt "$newer" -type f -print0)
}

# we need to export the function so we can
# run it in a bash subshell from xargs
export -f tarit

# we want to find newer files but output only the path(s)
# containing them with NULs as path separator rather than
# newlines, so use `-printf '%h\0'`.
find . ! -newermt "$today" -newermt "$yesterday" -type f -printf '%h\0' |
  sort -u -z |    # unique sort the directory list
  xargs -0r -I {} bash -c "tarit \"{}\" \"$today\" \"$yesterday\""
```

NOTE how all the variables are quoted for safety (even in the bash sub-shell, using escaped quoted), as well as using NUL as the separator (so the script won't break if pathnames and/or filenames contain annoying but completely valid characters like spaces or newlines).  Also note the use of indentation and extra spaces to improve readability.  And comments to explain what's being done and why.

If you just want to tar up the entire directory and delete the directory itself (and all files in it), it's simpler:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

    today='12am today'
yesterday='12am yesterday'    

find . ! -newermt "$today" -newermt "$yesterday" -type f -printf '%h\0' |
  sort -u -z |
  xargs -0r -I {} tar cfv "{}.tar" "{}" -C "{}/.." --remove-files
```

Personally, I think these are both incredibly dangerous scripts to use.  If you're not careful (e.g. running them as root with `/` instead of `.` as the find path...or just running them in the `/` directory), you can delete files and even entire directories needed  by the operating system.  Even running them under your uid in your home directory (or anywhere you have write acess to - which you'll need to create the tar files anyway) can delete files that you want to keep.

IMO you **really** need to rethink whether you actually need to use the `--remove-files` option of `tar`.  What are you trying to achieve?  Is this some kind of tmpreaper?  If so, then  just blindly deleting files in `/tmp` could break long-running processes that, e.g.,  created file(s) in /tmp yesterday and need to re-use them today...or tomorrow.

In short: **Here's a pair of loaded shotguns.  Try not to shoot yourself in the foot with them.**